# Reverse lookup value of ForeignKey (Child to Parent)

Tags: python, django

I'm in need of accessing a value the reverse way using ForeignKey. I want to go from child model `Category` to parent model `Post` and grab the value `title` into my template

I've tried `category.posts.title` but it isn't showing any success for me.

The main purpose of this is to create a `<div>` for each Category and list the blog posts with that category down below.

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default="Blog Post")
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='posts', default="2", unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

View:

```
def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        "posts": posts,
        "categories": categories,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)
```

Template

```
<div class="row">
<div style="padding: 0px;" class="col l12">
    {% for category in categories %}

<div class="col l3">
    <div style="background-color: white; box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 1px rgba(62,57,107,.07); border-radius: .6rem;" class="card ">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <div class="mb-4 pb-3"><i class="ti-briefcase text-muted font-40"></i></div>

            <h5 class="mb-3"> <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category %}">{{ category.name }}</a></h5>

            <div><a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center text-danger" ><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' category.name category.posts.slug category.posts.pk %}">{{ category.posts.title }}</a><i class="material-icons">
                keyboard_arrow_right
                </i></a></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the posts in each category

```
{% for post in category.posts.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_detail' category.name post.slug post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You should also use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) on your categories queryset to reduce the number of DB queries you make when you access `category.posts.all` as you no longer need your posts queryset

```
def blog_index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.annotate(
        post_count=Count('posts')
    ).prefetch_related('posts')
    context = {
        "categories": categories,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)
```

Added the [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) for getting the count of posts for each category

```
{% category.post_count %}
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on! Thanks for the help and the extra information regarding optimizing the database calls!

Comment: How can I count the total amount of posts under a given category? I tried `{{category.posts.title.count}}` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can use `category.posts.count` but this would perform a DB query per category. A better approach is to use `annotate`, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! I'm receiving this error in the views `name 'Count' is not defined`

Comment: You need to import Count: `from django.db.models import Count`

Answer (score 2):

As far as one `Category` can have multiple posts you would need to iterate over them:

```
category.posts.all()
```

In template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.name }}
    { % for post in category.posts.all %}
        {{ post.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Correct answer also, but chose to mark lain's answer as the correct one since he added some db optimization in his answer. Thanks!